# Getting a Singapore fiance visa after overstaying in the UK

Tags: visas, singapore, bangladeshi-citizens

My name is Shohab. I am from Bangladesh. I lived in the UK for nearly 10 years. For the last 4 years I overstayed my visa. I left the UK voluntarily.

My fiancée is a Singaporean resident. We have decided to get married in 2020. She will sponsor me for a resident visa. Should I declare that I overstayed in the UK for 4 years? If I don’t include that information, will that be a problem to get entry into Singapore?

Comment: Have you been asked this question as part of your application? If yes, tell the truth. If not, shut your mouth.